# ProcessStartInfo.RedirectOutput on .net compact framework

Tags: .net-cf-3.5

I would like to start an external process on the device and would like to capture its output. All the googling showed ProcessStartInfo.RedirectOutput - but it seems like this option is missing in .net compact framework.

Any ideas how this could be solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by using the memory mapped file from the OpenNETCF.IO project to get data from the called process back to the calling process.
Here is the link to the library: http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/